# Showing that a Sequence is defined recursively

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

How can I show that the sequence is defined recursively?

> Show that the recursively defined sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with
>   $$x_1=1, \qquad\qquad x_{n+1}=\sqrt{6+x_n}$$
>   converges and determine its limit

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL7BR.png)

Comment: What is the definition of recursion ?

Comment: "converges and determine its limit"

Answer (score 3):

The sequence is defined recursively, with initial value $x_1=1$ and 
with recursive relation $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{6+x_n}$. Your task is to prove that it converges and to determine its limit.

Convergence: There is a theorem that says that if a sequence is monotonically increasing and bounded from above, then it has a limit. This suggests the following:

1. Show that the sequence is monotonically increasing.
2. Show that the sequence is bounded from above.

Computing the limit: use the fact that as $n$ tends to infinity,
both $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ are roughly equal to the limit $L$.

3. Set $x_{n+1}=L$ and $x_n=L$, and extract the value of $L$.

Comment: Oh yes! My fault. I edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+...\sqrt{7}}}}<x$

If we go by induction :

$\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+...\sqrt{7}}}}=U_n<x$

$(U_{n+1})²-6=U_n<x$

$U_{n+1}<\sqrt{x+6}$

$\sqrt{x+6}=x$

---

- Now it is left to you calculating $x$ and $U_0$ testing part.